# How to staple layers in a view using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

How is it possible to staple layers, like in the picture below?

Preferably using ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop.

[image]

Comment: do you mean view them on top of eachother as if they were 3D? Have you tried assigning fictional Z values and viewing them in ArcScene?

Comment: I don't see it as a suggestion here, so I'll ask - an option is creating multiple data frames with your layers of interest, then laying those data frames out in layout view as you want them. Is this worth considering for you? You lose the perspective shift, but can still see the layers this way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to *whatahitson* I rendered a Scene in ArcScene. Add your Layers, then go to *Properties >> Base Heights >> Layer offset* for a vertical offset. However I don't see any options for a custom illustration, e.g. displaying labels or scales.

[image]

Comment: Sounds great! Unfortunately I only have the "ArcEditor" license. Is there any way to create this "15 degree" view in ArcMap?
If so I could do the combining in a photo editing software.

Answer (score 1):

This type of illustration is being created with raster processing software like photoshop.

In your snapshot each of the layers can be turned on individually and exported to a raster format e.g. PNG or JPEG.

First zoom to the extent of your layer and then go to:

File > Export > select JPEG or PNG as the datatype

Then those 7 layers need an extra work in  photoshop.

Comment: I've got polygon layers and would prefere to create JPEG views in ArcMap (see my comment to Monkey Joe) to edit them after an export. 
What do you think?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: check the updated answer